# PVS-Studio complaining about float comparison

Tags: c++, pvs-studio

I scanned my code with PVS Studio analyzer and I am confused on why this error and how to fix this.

V550 An odd precise comparison: * dest == value. It's probably better to use a comparison with defined precision: fabs(A - B) < Epsilon.

```
bool PipelineCache::SetShadowRegister(float* dest, uint32_t register_name) {
    float value = register_file_->values[register_name].f32;
    if (*dest == value) {
        return false;
    }
    *dest = value;
    return true;
}
```

I am guessing to change code like this:

```
bool PipelineCache::SetShadowRegister(float* dest, float* epsilon uint32_t register_name) {
    float value = register_file_->values[register_name].f32;
    return fabs(dest - value) < epsilon;
}
```

Comment: _"how to fix this"_ Exactly as proposed in the error message.

Comment: Since the condition `*dest == value` will be *true* on return either way, there doesn't seem to be any value in the `bool` return value. Otherwise, if this return value indicates a change in some 'cached' state, and this is the behaviour you want, just ignore the recommendation - since an *exact* comparison is what's required.

Comment: Unfortunately the advice to replace exact equality with test up to epsilon is bogus. You'll just need to ignore it.

Comment: Actually if you want to check for byte-by-byte equality you can either switch to using `uint32_t` instead of floats (at least for comparison) or replace `==` with `memcmp`.

Comment: We don't know, what your code is *supposed* to do, so we cannot make any recommendations on how to accomplish that, or whether the diagnostic requires an action on your part.

Comment: @VTT why would that be appropriate?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why wouldn't it be? This code seem to only care if the binary representation of values is the same.

Comment: @VTT no, it cares about floating point equality, quite different

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually the use of floating point equality is what this warning is all about, most likely it shouldn't be there. But I guess there is no point to argue about it because there is not enough context given.

Comment: @VTT Very plausible that it should be there. A common misconception made by those who don't really understand floating point is the belief that floating point equality should always be replaced by comparison against tolerance.

Comment: @VTT: `==` and `memcmp` will return different results on floating point values. For example, `+0.0` and `-0.0` have different binary representations, but must compare as equal. NaN's are another case, where the operations produce different results.

Comment: @IInspectable Changing comparison result is the whole point. For example right now if value is NaN this function will always return true and replace existing value, even if input will be the same every time. Such behavior of cache class most likely is not intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Whoever's wondering, we're talking about [this](https://github.com/benvanik/xenia/blob/master/src/xenia/gpu/vulkan/pipeline_cache.cc#L731) code.*

I'll try to explain what PVS studio developers were trying to achieve with this message. Citing their [reference](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V550/) about V550:

> Consider this sample:
>
> ```
> double a = 0.5;
> if (a == 0.5) //OK
>     x++;
>
> double b = sin(M_PI / 6.0);
> if (b == 0.5) //ERROR
>     x++;
> ```
>
> The first comparison 'a == 0.5' is true. The second comparison 'b == 0.5' may be both true and false. The result of the 'b == 0.5' expression depends upon the processor, compiler's version and settings being used. For instance, the 'b' variable's value was 0.49999999999999994 when we used the Visual C++ 2010 compiler.

What they are trying to say, is, comparing floating point numbers is tricky. If you just assign your floating point number, store it and move it around the memory to later compare with itself in this function - feel free to **dismiss** this error message.

If you are looking to perform some bit-representation check (which I honestly think you are doing), **see below**.

If you are performing some massive calculations on floating point numbers, and you are a game developer, calculating the coordinates of the enemy battlecruisers - this warning is one of your **best friends**.

---

Anyway, let's return to your case. As it usually happens with PVS-Studio, they did not see the exact error, but they pointed you to the right direction. You actually **want** to compare two float values, but you are doing it **wrong**. The thing is, if both float numbers you are comparing contain NaN (even in the same bit representation), you'll get `*dest != value`, and your code will not work in the way you want.

In this scenario, you better reinterpret the memory under `float *` as `uint32_t` (or whatever integer type has the same size as `float` on your target) and compare them instead.

For example, in your particular case, `register_file_->values[register_name]` is of [type](https://github.com/benvanik/xenia/blob/master/src/xenia/gpu/register_file.h#L41) `xe::gpu::RegisterFile::RegisterValue`, which already supports `uint32_t` representation.

*As a side effect, this will draw the warning away :)*

Comment: I am new to C++; let me see if I got this correct. Instead of if (*dest == value) { I use if (fabs(*dest - value)<FLT_EPSILON) {  return false;
  }
  *dest = value;
  return true;

Comment: @ThomasMccaffery In your particular case, you take `register_file_->values[register_name].u32`  and compare it with  something like `*(uint32_t *)dest`. Also, you might simply consider opening an issue in their bug tracker and see what they come up with, it's a nice way to learn :)

Comment: yes that is how I am learning. I feel the float and double has me confused the most and I think this what makes C++ the hardest. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasMccaffery please also consider upvoting and/or marking answers as "accepted" if you find them helpful.

Comment: @Thomas Why do you think that you need to change the code at all. This answer doesn't advise you to do that. Try to understand the code yourself.

Comment: @david like I said new to C++, but from what I read it's better to use epsilon to check floats and double values tp get more precision in the code am I correct? example would be like if (fabs(A - B) < FLT_EPSILON) choose a reasonable value to determine if two floats are "close enough" to be equal.

Comment: @Thomas sometimes that is right, sometimes it is wrong. It looks very much wrong here. I think it is foolhardy to change this code without understanding it. Certainly this static analysis tool doesn't understand it. I don't think you understand it. Why do you believe you know better than the original author.

Comment: To me it's the mention of `caching` in the code. If a floating point value (particular in a graphics / visualization context) has changed, even slightly, then the entire 'scene' may need to be recomputed. While I understand your point about an 'acceptable' tolerance - I'm sceptical in this case, and the context leads me to believe this warning is a false positive.

Comment: @BrettHale I'm afraid you've misread my answer. This particular piece of code is simulating the floating point registers of a guest system (in particular, it's an XBox emulator). In such case, comparing "old" and "new" values as regular floats is simply wrong. These guest floats might not even be related to any sort of graphics - imagine tolerance-based comarison of NaN values.

Comment: @iehrlich - you may be right. It's just a strange idiom to return a boolean when an updated float argument doesn't match the current state.